# Port mirroring not working through Vsphere

Tags: vmware-vsphere, netgear, port-mirroring

I have mirrored a port from Netgear switch to my VM on vsphere. I cannot see requests when using tcpdump to monitor the traffic, I only see replys.

Netgear port mirror works as i have connected a laptop directly to the port and with tcpdump it shows request and replys.

example ping using tcpdump on the vm host

```
tcpdump -i eth3 host ichigo.uk.domain.com
16:01:26.543729 IP janus.uk.domain.com > ichigo.uk.domain.com: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 13487, length 40
16:01:27.544376 IP janus.uk.domain.com > ichigo.uk.domain.com: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 13488, length 40
16:01:28.545339 IP janus.uk.domain.com > ichigo.uk.domain.com: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 13489, length 40
16:01:29.546428 IP janus.uk.domain.com > ichigo.uk.domain.com: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 13490, length 40
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a new vSwitch or portgroup for the incoming traffic? Does the VM have a dedicated interface for the tcpdump traffic?

If not, you should create one. On the vSwitch that you associate with this new interface, be sure to modify the **Policy Exceptions** options to "Accept".

[image]

Comment: i have already set this up and the mirrored traffic is being forwarded to the 2nd port of the VM, as i have mentioned i only see replys and no requests.